# Are there any specific official rules for playing 5e past lvl 20?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-levels

Upon reading the 5e Player's Handbook, I've noticed that the level cap seems to stop at a hard 20, which, too me, is too small. I've also read the Dungeon Master's Guide and found the Epic Boons system, but those all seem extremely under powered or over powered compared to one another. I've looked, to no avail, for an official system for playing past lvl 20, or at least an appealing homebrew one, but, as I said before, I have yet to find one.

Comment: Hi Aidanovski, and welcome to the site. I think the linked question answers yours. If that's not the case please [edit] this one to make the differences clear and flag this for reopening. Happy gaming!